# Trying to connect to a wsdl web service via android

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I want to connect to a WSDL based web service and simply display the String response in a TextView

**Code:**

```
package com.example.wsdlclient;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.taryatechnologies.com/ws/getCountry";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getCountry";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.taryatechnologies.com/ws";
    private static final String URL = "http://tarya.co.uk/ws/Ip2countryws.asmx?WSDL";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    request.addProperty("arg0", "49.248.145.220");

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);


                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


                    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                    final String str = response.toString();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                            TextView result;
                            result = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            result.setText(str);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        networkThread.start();
    }
}
```

The service is supposed to return a country name to which the IP belongs. 
I passed the IP through the request as:

> request.addProperty("arg0", "49.248.145.220");

**Also tried:**

> request.addProperty("ipnumb", "49.248.145.220");
>             //as ipnumb is the parameter ID.

**I get the following String (Error) as response:**

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Please help.

Comment: That error is from the web service.  You need to know the signature of the web service method to call it correctly but the error is exactly as it says.  It's expecting a string representing a double but is receiving a string which cannot be converted to a double.  Check with the web service provider.

Comment: Actually, I looked at the WSDL and it seems correct and this URL works http://tarya.co.uk/ws/Ip2countryws.asmx/getCountry?ipnumb=49.248.145.220.  Still think you need to check on the server side.

Comment: I mean on the server side, the method is expecting the IP in the form of a String which is exactly what I gave it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's my point, I don't think you are going wrong.  I suspect a bug in the web service.

Comment: I'm confused :(. Why does it return "Your Country/ISP is not listed" i.e., when tested on the browser?

Comment: Guess I'll try a different service. Simple WSDL services are hard to find. Any links would be appreciated. :) Thanks!